# windows phone 8.1 microphone line in audio streaming

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, audio-streaming, microphone

I'm trying to pass some data from one phone to another while the both are connected via the audio jackets(3.5mm) with an appropriate cable.
How do I know if my phone can catch data through the 3.5mm audio jacket? 
I some some posts say that there is no way to catch data through the line in audio jacket but there are several apps which make use of this audio jacket any way.... 
And if the answer is yes, how do I set the line in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass data through a 3.5mm jack, in smartphones, it is made for sound output, and its only use is sound+mic with compatible headset...
Use bluetooth instead ..